# Refreshing body classes using Djax/Pjax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pjax

I'm using [Djax](https://github.com/beezee/djax) as a way of integrating Pjax on my site. For the most part it works great, but one feature I would like to integrate is refreshing body classes after a load event. The issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/beezee/djax/issues/37) and [here](https://github.com/beezee/djax/issues/5) but no real solution has been suggested (although the author suggests it should be easy to do).

Using the [djaxLoad](https://github.com/beezee/djax#djaxload) function you can work with some of the data from the requested page but I'm unsure if this contains the body classes.

> As a convenience, the data object passed with the event contains the
>   requested url, the page title for the requested page, and the contents
>   of the requested page as a string. Use something like the following
>   code to work with the response as a jQuery object

```
$(window).bind('djaxLoad', function(e, data) {
    var responseObj = $('<div>'+data.response+'</div>');
    //do stuff here
});
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm also open to other options other than Djax/Pjax if there is a simpler solution I am overlooking.